# Un-cross out the css property from the user end

Tags: css, firefox, css-sprites

When I enter the high-contrast mode in Windows 7, The background images becomes invisible. It is OS actively crossing out all `background` properties in CSS. (I am not certain how this works). I was wondering if these properties can be overridden and become visible using a extension or user-styled css.

For example, here is the CSS property for the background image on Amazon.com that got crossed out (includes the image for the rating stars)

```
.srSprite {
    background: url("http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/nav2/images/gui/searchSprite._V373035005_.gif") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

I tried to make these visible by putting the following in the Stylish style. Stylish is a Firefox add-on to customize CSS.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(http://), url-prefix(https://), url-prefix(ftp://){
.srSprite{
    background: no-peat scroll 0 0 transparent !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: relative !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;

}
}
```

but it does not seem to work. Did I do something wrong, or is there some other ways to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is by-design behaviour. The purpose of high contrast mode is to make everything more accessible, which includes stripping out 'noise' like background images which can reduce contrast.

This [blog post](http://terrillthompson.com/blog/182) has more information on the paradigm of Windows high contrast mode. Something most of us should probably think more about (me included).

Comment: I came across this page before, but if you look at firebug, the CSS information is there, it is just that the browser is complying to OS and not displaying the sprites. I believe that this is something that could be overcome by the end-user and I am seeking a solution. Maybe it needs some hack. Perhaps WC3 non-compliant web-browser... hopefully not.

Comment: Oh, you're an end user looking to overcome this? I assumed you were a developer looking to work around it on your own website. Couldn't you just simulate a high-contrast schema with Windows colors but use a normal contrast base to avoid the overrides?

An alternative may be to use a Virtual Machine with a regular contrast theme inside it, running a browser. You could probably run a light `Linux` distro inside 512 RAM with `Chromium`.